# Comparison of all the rows inside a column on the same table

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I created a sample data frame as below:

```
data = {'X': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90],
        'Y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
       }

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now I need to find the distance between two points for the above sample data set, to that, I had already defined a function

```
import numpy as np
def dist(X1,Y1,X2,Y2):
     #find the distance between 2 points
    d = np.sqrt((X2 - X1) * (X2 - X1) + (Y2 - Y1) * (Y2 - Y1))
    
    return d
```

I need to  find the distance between 2 points, as example, if I used the 1st row I need to compare that row with all the other rows in the same data frame column, Then I need to use 2nd row and compare that row with all the other rows in the same column and so on until all the rows had compared with each other

To do this I used a nested for loop as below

```
res = []

for i in range(0,len(df_test)):
    X1 = df_test.A[i]
    Y1 = df_test.B[i]
    
    for j in range(0,len(df_test)):
        X2 = df_test.A[j]
        Y2 = df_test.B[j]
        
     
        res = dist(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)
        
        print(res)
    print( )
```

**How can I do the above-mentioned process without using a nested for loop , since this method will work with a small number of rows in a data frame but when dealing with large datasets terminal will get killed**